# C#, Processes output sometimes doesn't get captured (inconsistency)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, redirect, output-redirect

The program I made throws off threads which start executables through processes. Each thread runs the method below which starts the process and redirects the processes' output into a string (info.additional which is per process). 
I've learned through a lot of trial and error that I have to redirect output a certain way (using events for output received) or else the streams deadlock. 
Now, I'm running on a dual core machine and if I have two threads running and starting processes, the program runs great and captures the output of these processes perfectly. But when I move to more than two threads (more threads than I have cores) the output sometimes doesn't get captured for these. Why is this? And does anyone know how to fix this? 
Thank you, Joe

```
    public void ThreadProc()
    {
        info.watch.Start();
        proc = InstantiateProcess();
        proc.Start();
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
    }


    private void procOutputDataReceived(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            this.info.additional += e.Data.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It isn't clear whether info.additional is per-process.  If it is not then you have to put a lock around it.

Comment: Sorry about that yes it creates a new instance for each thread sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this could be causing the problem, but based on the code here your `ThreadProc` is exiting before the `Process` object is done. According to the [OutputDataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) docs, you should be calling `WaitForExit()` "The application that is processing the asynchronous output should call the WaitForExit() method to ensure that the output buffer has been flushed." Based on that line I would assume you could lose some data if you are not doing that.

On an unrelated note, `Process` objects implement IDisposable so I would recommend changing your ThreadProc method like this (note I don't see a declaration of proc here, but as you say you launch multiple processes I am assuming that proc is not a member variable and the declaration was just left out in the sample):

```
public void ThreadProc()
{
    info.watch.Start();
    using (var proc = InstantiateProcess())
    {
        proc.Start();
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        proc.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much man! This fixed it. Man I was at a loss here. I'll read msdn next time I have a question.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you make sure to *keep* the references to the `Process` objects, they will be garbage collected, in which case events on them will stop firing.

Simple solution:

- store the `Process` objects until the process has terminated